# Bundle splitting with Webpack 4 - duplicate vendor bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

We have a legacy multipage application where each page has its own js file. We use Webpack 4 and now we start to use react as well. I want to separate react bundle from our own code. So each page loads its own legacy pageXJS.js file, the new pageXReact.js file, and the react.bundle.js

We have a webpack config below that works almost fine.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const jsModuleFolder = './src/main/resources/static/js/module/';

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        'pageA/pageAJS': jsModuleFolder + 'pageA/pageAJS.js',
        'pageB/pageBJS': jsModuleFolder + 'pageB/pageBJS.js',
        'pageC/pageCJS': jsModuleFolder + 'pageC/pageCJS.js',
        'pageC/PageCReact': jsModuleFolder + 'pageC/pageCReact.js',
        vendor: ['react', 'react-dom']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, jsModuleFolder )
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    test: 'vendor',
                    name: '../react/react',
                    enforce: true
                }
            },
        },
    },
};
```

It generates the react.bundle.js in the react folder. However, it also generates a vendor.bundle.js file in the module folder. The vendor.bundle.js is just a webpackBoostrap file without real content. The webpackBootstrap is also part of the generated PageCReact.bundle.js so the vendor.bundle.js seems to be unnecessary. (And my site works fine without it.)

How can I prevent this file from being generated as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's the runtime file and is needed by webpack.

You can include the file in your entry point file like this:

```
optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: false // <-- set to false
```

I would suggest to configure it like this:

```
optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single', // creates a single runtime chunk for all entry points.
```

Comment: With our original config, the runtime code is part of the generated pageCReact.js. And it is ok. Even if I use `runtimeChunk: 'single' ` the vendor.bundle.js is still generated but it is much smaller (of course as runtime part was generated into another file.)

Comment: With `runtimeChunk: 'single'` you get a single, separate, pure bootstrap file, you cannot ommit it, but it also doesn't hurt. Perhaps create a little repo, to see what exactly happens and what the problem is.